# Migrating SharePoint Product Catalog List at Subsite level

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, backup, sharepoint-2013, restore

I am trying to Migrate SharePoint Product Catalog List from to a Sub-site using List template backup/Restore and getting error

Something Went Wrong.

While checking the LOGS with the correlation ID

```
Application error when access /_layouts/15/new.aspx, Error=Value does not fall within the expected range.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateListFromFormPost(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrGuid, String& pbstrNextUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateListFromFormPost(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrGuid, String& pbstrNextUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.CreateListFromRpc(NameValueCollection queryString, Uri& nextUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.NewListPage.BtnOk_Click(Object sender, EventArgs args)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)         883aeb9c-fdf6-301a-75c9-3a32ec634865

System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateListFromFormPost(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrGuid, String& pbstrNextUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateListFromFormPost(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrGuid, String& pbstrNextUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.CreateListFromRpc(NameValueCollection queryString, Uri& nextUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.NewListPage.BtnOk_Click(Object sender, EventArgs args)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)         883aeb9c-fdf6-301a-75c9-3a32ec634865
```

**Using Power shell Also getting the same error**

Answer (score 0):

As per as my knowledge and understanding , Microsoft has not provide any solution for this, If you will try to create any product catalogue list using stp that too you cant do.